# Determine which thread exception occurred in DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a WPF app in which we are using tasks to invoke new threads. I have an App_DispatcherUnhandledException event in the code to catch any areas that occur on any thread, which works fine. For the purposes of logging however I'd like to determine whether the exception occured on main thread or on a task. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event args object has a `Dispatcher` property, which has a `Thread` property:

Dispatcher.UnhandledException Event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

DispatcherUnhandledExceptionFilterEventArgs Class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherunhandledexceptionfiltereventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

DispatcherEventArgs.Dispatcher Property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchereventargs.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

You can name threads, or store the managed ID of the main one to identify the thread from that.

Hope that helps!